# Return const dictionary

Tags: dictionary, constants, julia

In Julia, suppose I have a function that returns a dictionary:

```
function f()
    d = [i => 2i for i = 1:10]
    return d
end
```

I would like to return the dictionary as const. That is, keys cannot be added or removed, and existing keys cannot be reassigned. Is it possible to modify `f` so that the returned dictionary is const?

Comment: What to you mean by the dictionary being const? From [the manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/variables-and-scoping/#constants):

Note that `const` only affects the variable binding; the variable may be bound to a mutable object (such as an array), and that object may still be modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia's standard library does not provide an immutable associative type. You could implement such a type yourself and not define any `setindex!` method for it. It might be easier to simply not mutate the returned dictionary, however.

Answer (score 4):

Although Julia doesn't have a readonly Dict in its standard library (there is the unexported `ImmutableDict`, but that only prevents deletions, not sets), nor in the `DataStructures.jl` package, it could fairly easily be added as a package.

There are a number of advantages of a readonly Dict, for example, a perfect hash function can be generated so that entries are found (or not) with only a single probe. (https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html describes a tool to generate a perfect hash).

Comment: If the number of keys might be somewhat large (as it may in this case), CMPH is likely to be a better choice than gperf: http://cmph.sourceforge.net/index.html. It is also LGPL whereas gperf is GPL. You can find an example usage of CMPH here: https://github.com/StefanKarpinski/bam. If anyone is interested in pursuing this project, the CHD algorithm works well and would be simple to implement in pure Julia. I would recommend not reading the CMPH source in that case and using an MIT license for the resulting library.

Comment: If bam is based on CMPH, then one should not read the source code for that either (to avoid licensing issues later), correct?  From the README alone, bam sounds very nice.  If not done before then, maybe making a package using CHD could be a decent idea for a Julia GSoC 2017 project?

Comment: bam uses CMPH, it's not derived from it, so the bam source is fine to read or use.